# Run Macro to create a copy of workbook without links each time workbook is saved

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA so what I have come up with so far has been found online. I have a workbook that is a culmination of several other workbooks...so it has many links to several other workbooks. I need to essentially copy the workbook data without the links to send outside the company. I found the code to do this and it works properly. The problem is I want this to happen every time the workbook is saved. I found code for that also, but when I try to combine the two, excel crashes. Below is the code for creating a copy of the workbook:

```
Sub nowe_poprawione()

    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim Current As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Set Output = ThisWorkbook
    Current = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    For Each SH In Output.Worksheets

        SH.UsedRange.Copy
        SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

    Next

    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
    Output.SaveAs FileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Current
    Output.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This is the code to run the macro each time it is saved:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
End Sub
```

This is what I came up with to combine the two that causes excel to crash:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Sub nowe_poprawione()

    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim Current As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Set Output = ThisWorkbook
    Current = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    For Each SH In Output.Worksheets

        SH.UsedRange.Copy
        SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

    Next

    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
    Output.SaveAs FileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Current
    Output.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a subroutine inside a subroutine the way you have done:

```
Sub foo()
Sub bar()
End Sub
```

Instead, you can call one subroutine from the other:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Run "nowe_poprawione"
End Sub
```